# How to include graphics exported from Inkscape as pdf/tex?

Tags: graphics, inkscape

I have exported an Image from Inkscape to PDF/TEX. When trying to add it using

```
\input{images/myfile.pdf_tex}
```

I get an error

```
"Package pdftex.def Error: File `myfile.pdf` not found: ...
```

The [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) suggests that I should use `\graphicspath{{images/}}` so I have added that to my preamble but it still doesn't work. What's my mistake?

Edit:
I also tried the alternative from the documentation to add `\usepackage{import}` to the preamble and add the image with `\import{images}{myfile.pdf_tex}` but it didn't work either. It results in

```
File `myfile.pdf_tex` not found...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is `myfile.pdf_tex` and `myfile.pdf` in the same folder? `images/`? The n you can use `\graphicspath`, but you are using it wrong, the correct syntax is `\graphicspath{{./images/}}`, note a set of braces around each folder added this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

not

```
\graphicspath{images/}
```

then

```
\input{images/myfile.pdf_tex}
```

should work, or instead you can set TEXINPUTS to `./images:` in the enviornment before calling pdftex then

```
\input{myfile.pdf_tex}
```

should work as tex and graphics files are found on the TEXINPUTS path.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy error. I did have the extra braces and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Elias we can only answer the questions as posted, please edit the question to show a small complete example that can be run to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to put the `\graphicspath` right above the line that included the image instead of in the preamble. So this worked:

```
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\input{images/myimage.pdf_tex}
```

Comment: That should not be necessary unless you're also messing with the graphics path in the preamble. Did you add it before or after loading `graphicx`?

Comment: @daleif I don't explicitly load graphicx at all it seems to be included in the .cls with \RequirePackage

Comment: Then you really ought to tell us more about this document. There is a reason why we always ask for a full but minimal example. A side reason is to get an idea of either badly prepared templates (there are a _lot_) or other setups that do things in ways that are undesirable for all users.

Comment: @daleif It's publicly available here: https://github.com/wannesm/adsphd

Comment: well, it is definitely doing stuff that it should not. Are you using `\includechapter`, it is explicitly resetting the graphicspath, nullifying what ever was there to begin with. I guess they are trying to force a specific directory structure with this class. See why this sort of information is important. Also it does not support xelatex or lualatex, as it is explicitly passing `pdftex` or `dvips` to graphicx.